# Unable to connect SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server 2005 DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, connectivity

I have SQL Server 2005 on my work station and on my Server, we have SQL Server 2008. When I tried to connect to SQL Server 2008 from my SQL Server 2005 edition, I am receiving the following error:

> This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio can only be
>   used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers.

Without installing SQL Server 2008 on my workstation, is there any way for me to connect to SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server 2005 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue.  Please see the following KB article for a resolution: [FIX: You may experience problems when you use SQL Server Management Studio in SQL Server 2005 to connect to an instance of SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946127)

Answer (score 1):

You can install a newer version of Management Studio on your workstation without changing or replacing your SQL Server 2005 instance.

Ideally, the machine where you manage from has a version of Management Studio that is always >= the highest version of any instance that you manage.